# Получить сумму значений колонки таблицы, сравнивая дату с датой из другой таблицы

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблицы:

Table1

```
Id| Val | Date
 1|  3  | 2020-03-10 00:00:00
 2|  9  | 2020-02-23 00:00:00
 3|  4  | 2020-02-25 00:00:00
 4|  5  | 2020-03-14 00:00:00
```

Table2

```
SomeDate
2020-02-28 00:00:00
2020-03-31 00:00:00
```

Пытаюсь написать запрос, который будет брать каждую дату из `Table2` по очереди,
по ней находить записи в `Table1`, где `Table1.Date < Table2.SomeDate`,
и суммировать значения колонки `Val`.

В результате должны быть записи с 2-мя колонками - `sum(Table1.Val)`, `Table2.SomeDate`:

```
sum(Table1.Val) | Table2.SomeDate
     13         | 2020-02-28 00:00:00
     21         | 2020-03-31 00:00:00
```

Думал, что должно быть что-то вроде:

```
select sum(t1.val), t2.SomeDate 
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2
where t1.Date < t2.SomeDate
```

Но запрос не рабочий.

Comment: А почему для `'2020-03-31 00:00:00'` результат 8? Условию `Table1.Date < Table2.SomeDate` соответствуют все 4 записи, и результат должен быть 21.

Comment: Akina , да Вы правы, поправил.

Comment: А что такое - _запрос не правильный_?

Comment: не рабочий, т.е. не даёт той выборки, которую ожидалось получить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запрос в принципе правильный, но его надо немного поправить:

- нельзя именовать колонки в таблицах зарезервироваными ключевыми словами (`date` в данном случае)
- надо включать в `GROUP BY` колонки, которые в листе выборки и не являются параметрами агрегирующих функций

Итого, такой запрос рабочий:

```
select sum(t1.val) sumval, t2.SomeDt 
from t1, t2
where t1.Dt < t2.SomeDt
group by t2.SomeDt
```

Если версия 12.01 или позднее, то эффективней будет с кореляционным запросом:

```
select sumval, t2.SomeDt 
from t2 
cross apply (
    select sum (t1.val) sumval
    from t1
    where t1.Dt < t2.SomeDt)
```

Оба запроса дадут желаемый результат:

```
    SUMVAL SOMEDT             
---------- -------------------
        13 2020-02-28 00:00:00
        21 2020-03-31 00:00:00
```

---

CTE с тестовыми данными для примеров выше:

```
with t1 (Id, Val, Dt) as ( 
    select 1,  3,  date'2020-03-10' from dual union all
    select 2,  9,  date'2020-02-23' from dual union all
    select 3,  4,  date'2020-02-25' from dual union all
    select 4,  5,  date'2020-03-14' from dual
), t2 (SomeDt) as (
    select date'2020-02-28' from dual union all
    select date'2020-03-31' from dual
) 
[здесь вставить сам запрос]
```

Comment: спасибо! Не хватало группировки.